# Array with user-defined size filled with random numbers

Tags: java, arrays, random

I'm trying to make an array that is user-defined how big the array is, and then my program should randomly put numbers in the array.

Another obstacle I came across is how to filter the array and get rid of duplicates?

```
    package question3;

    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.Random;

    public class DuplicateTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

         Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("enter number of elements");

            int n=s.nextInt();

            int arr[]=new int[n];

            Random rand = new Random();
            int MAX_RAND_INT = 10;
            for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){//for reading array
                arr[i]=rand.nextInt(MAX_RAND_INT);
            }

            for(int i: arr){ //for printing array

                System.out.print(" "+i+",");

            }
    }
```

}

Comment: Also for some reason my code doesn't get rid of duplicates????

Comment: you don't want duplicates? then the declared array size won't be equal to the numbers inserted?

Comment: Like I need to print the random generated array but then print a filtered list without the duplicates  , so do I need to print another list and makes sure there isn't duplicates rather then the array?

Comment: i edited my code and description

Comment: but then only some values between 0-9 will be printed, is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, this is what I want to do, I think I will need to print the array unfiltered first then save another array as the `filteredArray` and then print that to complete the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just

```
import java.util.Random;
```

And then create a new random object

```
Random rand = new Random();
```

And get a random integer (feel free to have a min and max);

```
int MAX_RAND_INT = 100;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){//for reading array
    arr[i]=rand.nextInt(MAX_RAND_INT);
}
```

Read the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) for more detail on the API.

Comment: Yeah in the question I have to do the random number generated has to be between 0-9??

Comment: @Phantom1421 then in the example above you would put `int MAX_RAND_INT = 10` to be able to get between 0-9